# While counting number of rows this code gives wrong result(usually more than the answer)?

Tags: java, matrix

Given two integers N and M and a matrix of dimensions N*M. Count all the rows in a matrix that are sorted either in strictly increasing order or in strictly decreasing order.

```
class Solution {
    int sortedCount(int N, int M, int Mat[][]) {
        // code here
        int g=0,f=0,c=0;
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
          for(int j=0;j<(M-1);j++){
            
            if(Mat[i][j]-Mat[i][j+1]==1){
              g++;
            }
        
            else if(Mat[i][j+1]-Mat[i][j]==1){
              f++;
            }
        
          }
        
          if(g==(M-1)||f==(M-1)){
            c++;
          }
        
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a few more details? What is "not working perfectly"? Wrong result? A crash? Only working for certain inputs?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but from my understanding "strictly increasing" means "each value greater than the value before", but you are checking for a difference of 1 exactly. Also, why do you check `g` and `f` for the value 2? If your matrix has 3 rows or columns, these variables will hold 3, not 2. Moreover, g and f are never reset between loop iterations. For the second row, you will keep adding to the value of the first row.